# How to run multiple tasks in single data flow task in SSIS project

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

i have an issue that , i ran multiple data flow tasks in single control flow, if 5 out of 5 source alive it works fine but any one source is dead, it is not executing remaining 4 source flows,how to run which ever is alive should run smoothly when ever we are executing the job

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the 5 data flows are all connected together on the control flow. The desire is to have all 5 data flows execute, regardless of success or failure of the previous data flow.

To accomplish this, you will need to change the Precedence Constraint from the current value of Success (green) to Completion (blue). To access the Precedence Constraint Editor, double click the connector line and you should see the following.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to place all 5 data flow tasks in a sequence container and have them run in parallel (by not connecting them to each other).  It would look something like this:

[image]